# Is there any logical concept that Rust lifetimes correspond to?

Tags: linear-logic

We're all used to invoking Curry–Howard to find correspondences between type systems and logical systems.

Rust has a very interesting type system, that is typically compared to a substructural logic. However, the concept of a "lifetime" doesn't seem to correspond to anything syntax-level in e.g. affine or linear logic, at least as much as I can understand them (not much).

The internet search yielded a [discussion](https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/rust-lifetimes-semantics-at-mathematical-level/6499/11) of mathematical ideas applicable to the lifetimes. However, it just talks about the mathematical properties of lifetimes. Curry-Howard bridge doesn't seem to be crossed. Are there any "properly" *logical* ideas that might (more-or-less) correspond to Rust lifetimes?

Comment: Probably no direct CH-correspondence. Rust's types trace back to linear types in process calculus and linear logic. Wadler's [Propositions as Sessions](https://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/wadler/papers/propositions-as-sessions/propositions-as-sessions.pdf) might be a place to start looking.

Comment: Maybe Taha/Nielsen's concept of [*environment classifiers*](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/640128.604134), which arose in the concept of typed meta-programming, is close enough to Rust lifetimes that Tsukadai / Igarashi's work   [A Logical Foundation for Environment Classifiers](https://arxiv.org/abs/1010.3806), which gives a CH-correspondence for ECs, could be a starting point?